# How to insert a field that contains a modified value of a row

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_random` (
  `i_domain` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_domain_no_http` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `i_domain_UNIQUE` (`i_domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have created the field `i_domain_no_http` using alter table. It is a new column (no value there it is initial set to NULL) where I want to insert the exact values of `i_domain` but after modifying them and removing a prefix `http://`./

I made the query:

```
insert into `myscheme`.`new_random` (`new_random`.`i_domain_no_http`)
select substring_index(`new_random`.`i_domain`,'http://',-1)
from `myscheme`.`new_random`;
```

Example, the table should look like:

```
i_domain       | i_domain_no_http
------------------------------------
http://11.com  | 11.com
https://22.com | 22.com
```

But I am getting this error:

```
i_domain       | i_domain_no_http
------------------------------------
http://11.com  | 
https://22.com | 
NULL           | 11.com
NULL           | 22.com
```

The 'i_domain' should be a primary key and not NULL but I had to remove the `NN` and `PK` to avoid the error:

```
Error Code: 1364. Field 'i_domain' doesn't have a default value
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE myscheme.new_random 
SET i_domain_no_http = SUBSTRING_INDEX(new_random.i_domain,'://',-1)
```

Output:

```
i_domain        i_domain_no_http
http://11.com   11.com
https://22.com  22.com
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=017d4d88834bb71193d38497b3d318e4)